# how to restrict user to only particular action and modify when needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, roles

I am using devise for authentication and i want only user named `admin` having permission to edit or delete all the posts. The other users can view all the posts specific to any project. And only the users corresponding to that project can edit the posts. 
Also we should able to change the user from one project to another. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an authorization solution. Check [this](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization) and choose one.

Answer (score 0):

Cancan gem is used for authorization, this gem may help you https://github.com/ryanb/cancan